# make two or more pages in one single view in ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework to make mobile application in which i am now doing the setting page that has many options you can click in. but now i come across a problem that we do not know how to make two or more pages in one single view in ionic
my code:

//when i make one view like the one below, it works

```
      .state('tabs.settingMyNeeds', {
        url:'/setting/:aId',
        views:{
          'setting-tab':{
            templateUrl:'/travelAbroad/public/travel/www/templates/settingMyNeeds.html',
            controller:'expatsController'
          }
        }

      })
```

//but when i add one more like, it fails to open the My Info link :

```
      .state('tabs.settingMyNeeds', {
        url:'/setting/:aId',
        views:{
          'setting-tab':{
            templateUrl:'/travelAbroad/public/travel/www/templates/settingMyNeeds.html',
            controller:'expatsController'
          }
        }

      })
      .state('tabs.settingMyInfo', {
        url:'/setting/info/:aId',
        views:{
          'setting-tab':{
            templateUrl:'/travelAbroad/public/travel/www/templates/settingMyInfo.html',
            controller:'expatsController'
          }
        }

      });
```

//and my html

```
        <div class="list">

            <a class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right" href="#" ng-repeat="expat in expats | filter: {id: loginedId} | limitTo:1" href="./#/tab/setting/info/{{expat.id}}">
              <i class="icon ion-ios-information-outline"></i>
                My Info
              <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-thin-right"></i>
            </a>

             <a class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right" ng-repeat="expat in expats | filter: {id: loginedId} | limitTo:1" href="./#/tab/setting/{{expat.id}}">
              <i class="icon ion-ios-help-outline"></i>
                My Needs
              <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-thin-right"></i>
            </a>               
           </div><!--end of list-->
```

can anybody help me , Many thanks

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: nope,seems nothing showing. the My Needs link always shows: http://localhost/travelAbroad/public/#, not what i set it as http://localhost/travelAbroad/public/#/tab/setting/{{expat.id}}

Comment: Could you try putting the info state above the needs state?

Comment: Exchange each other's place? I do change it but failed to work

Comment: Modify your `href` like this: `href="#/tab/setting/info/{{expat.id}}"`

Comment: i do  but not working. and seems the problem is not here,thanks

Comment: your way of the url is right. and i just fix it. so can you post the solution below, so i can accept your answer,thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your views need to have a unique name. Also, your urls should be more specific to allow ui router to distinguish between them. Try this:

```
.state('tabs.settingMyNeeds', {
url:'/setting/needs/:aId',
views:{
  'setting-tab-myneeds':{
    templateUrl:'/travelAbroad/public/travel/www/templates/settingMyNeeds.html',
    controller:'expatsController'
  }
}

})
.state('tabs.settingMyInfo', {
url:'/setting/info/:aId',
views:{
  'setting-tab-myinfo':{
    templateUrl:'/travelAbroad/public/travel/www/templates/settingMyInfo.html',
    controller:'expatsController'
  }
}

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. but i do not want to make another tab. i just wanna make a page that is based on the setting-tab